# Tensorflow: Add function returning first tensor as result

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

This was a simple add function to add two tensors:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
#print("first")
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
#print("second")
result_node = tf.add(a,b)
#print("starting")
x = session.run(result_node, {a:2.0, b: 3.5})
print(x)
```

One would expect 5.5 as result

But the result is:
2.0

Tried adding 1 rank as well,

```
print(session.run(result_node, {a:[1.0,2.0], b:[4.2,1.2323]}))
```

Output: [ 1.  2.]

Comment: Are u sure? because it gave me 5.5

Comment: that's what I am wondering, it isn't making sense. Could it be a wrong installation?

Comment: I could not reproduce either: got `5.5` and `[5.2 3.2323]` respectively. Are you sure the code you're running is exactly as in the question?